# UWP location tracking even when the app was suspended

Tags: c#, uwp

I‘m developing a UWP running app, and I want to record user's location in real time.I've read many threads throw google, and got some solutions as: [ExtendedExecutionSession](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/954186cf-ac3b-4c8a-9539-9c9e728eba1c/uwpcontinious-location-tracking-in-universal-windows-apps?forum=wpdevelop) , [app service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187314.aspx). But these two solutions have a same problem: cannot record the location when app is suspended. I know the background task in uwp, it seems need a trigger(e. g. SystemTrigger) to launch. Is it possible to launch (do not use trigger but call directly) a custom background task when app is suspended to track/record location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would like to answer your question:

> Is it possible to launch (do not use trigger but call directly) a
>   custom background task when app is suspended to track/record location?

Yes, you can do this with the ApplicationTrigger class. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.applicationtrigger
(It's still a trigger, since the API needs it, but it basically calls the backgroundtask directly from the app)

But here are some samples for doing location tracking and these kind of things:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Geolocation

I think what you are looking for is the LocationTrigger (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.locationtrigger) 
It is used in the Geofence sample (Scenario5_GeofenceBackgroundTask.xaml.cs)

Basically you register it like this: (it’s from the sample code)

```
BackgroundTaskBuilder geofenceTaskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
geofenceTaskBuilder.Name = SampleBackgroundTaskName;
geofenceTaskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = SampleBackgroundTaskEntryPoint;

var trigger = new LocationTrigger(LocationTriggerType.Geofence);

geofenceTaskBuilder.SetTrigger(trigger);


_geofenceTask = geofenceTaskBuilder.Register();
//...and do the rest (but look into the sample..everything is from there...)
```

Comment: gregk, thanks for your answer. I'll try the ApplicationTrigger.

Comment: I extended my answer just after you commented.. I would also try the LocationTrigger. I don't know your exact requirements, but for tracking locations that would be the way to go..

Comment: I saw your newest answer, thanks again. My exact requirement is: continuing track/record user's current location even when the app is suspended.

Comment: Raymond, did you ever find the answer to this issue. I have tried App Service but does not run under suspend mode.